# Error in l1[i] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable

Tags: r

I am trying to find a matrix of Overlaps between two clusters. 
I set an s4 class which have one slot (list contain all clusters).

```
 setClass("A", representation(a="list"))

 setMethod("initialize","A",
      function(.Object,data,k){
          fit<-kmeans(data,k)
          c<-list()
          for(i in 1:k)
              c[[i]]<-data[fit$cluster==i,]
          .Object@a<-c
          return(.Object)
      })

 l1<-new("A", da1, 4)
 l2<-new("A", da1, 4)
```

I tried to find the common elements in both object of class "A", using code

```
for(i in 1:4)
{
    for(j in 1:4)
    {
        lap[i,j]<-length(merge(l1[[i]],l2[[j]], all.x = FALSE, all.y = FALSE))
}
```

}

it gives me error message

```
 Error in l1[[i]] : this S4 class is not subsettable
```

My question is how i can write a method which calculate this overlap.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for why you're using S4?

Comment: if you use `l1@a[[i]]` and `l2@a[[j]]` in place of `l1[[i]]` and l2[[j]]` does that fix the error?

Comment: No there is not such a particular reason for using s4 class. But after finding overlap matrix I will trace transition of clusters using another function. And clustering might be at more than 2 time steps so i tried s4.

Comment: No even    l1@a[[i]]  is not working